# Simple error: expected primary-expression before ';' token

Tags: c++, function, matrix, syntax-error

I'm writing a function to create a perspective projection matrix and I'm getting some errors. Can you help me?
I've marked the lines with error with '-'

```
typedef GLfloat mat4x4[16];
```

function:

```
void perspective(float fovy, float aspect, float near, float far, mat4x4& mat)
{
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
        mat[i]=0;
    -float range = tan(degreesToRadians(fovy)/2.0f) * near;
    float left = range * aspect;
    float right = range * aspect;
    float bottom = range;
    float top = range;
    -mat[0] = (2.0f * near) / (right - left);
    -mat[5] = (2.0f * near) / (top - bottom);
    --mat[10] = (far + near) / (far - near);
    -mat[11] = 1.0f;
    -mat[14] = (2.0f * far * near) / (far - near);
}
```

errors:

```
In function 'void perspective(float, float, float, float, GLfloat (&)[16])':

błąd:expected primary-expression before ';' token
błąd:expected primary-expression before ')' token
błąd:expected primary-expression before ')' token
błąd:expected primary-expression before ')' token
błąd:expected primary-expression before ')' token
błąd:expected primary-expression before ')' token
błąd:expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

Comment: What do you think `-float` means? Similarly, `-mat[0] = ...` may be meaningful, but I doubt it.

Comment: in code it's not -float it's just float

Comment: I've just marked the lines with errors

Comment: Ah I see. You should always post the **exact** code that causes the error, so people can just copy/paste/compile.

Comment: in line --mat[10] = (far + near) / (far - near); I've used '-' twice because it gave me 2 errors

Comment: A quick dummy version compiles fine: https://ideone.com/EAzoPi

Comment: What is the definition of `degreesToRadians`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you're including an evil header that defines `near` and `far` as macros. These were used on ancient 16-bit versions of Windows to qualify pointers (although, if memory serves, I think the DOS/Windows headers themselves used the less evil `NEAR` and `FAR`), and it's possible that some vestige of that weirdness still exists.

Either avoid using those names; or find a way to avoid these macro definitions; or switch to a platform with less backward-compatiblity baggage to trip over.

Comment: thank you, I've just changed the names of variables and I'ts working.